# How does one check if a byte contains a specific pattern of bits?

Tags: c++, math

At first I just wanted to know how many 8 bit numbers contained either 111 or 000, but I couldn't find any math based answer but couldn't find any. Probably because I couldn't word it right.

Now I just want to know how to check with an algorithm, I tried in c++ because I recently learned it.
Here's where I've got so far:

```
    int count = 0;
    unsigned char base = 0;

    //for every permutation of origin
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < 0b100000000; i++)
    {
        bool hasPattern = false;
        unsigned char pattern = 0b1110000;
        unsigned char temp = base;

        //for as many times as (length of base)-(length of pattern)
        for (char j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            //get rid of the bits we aren't checking
            temp >>= j;
            temp <<= 5;
            //check if what remains matches our pattern
            if ((pattern & temp) == pattern || (~pattern & temp) == ~pattern)
            {
                hasPattern = true;
            }
        }
        //if the pattern matches, increment count
        count += hasPattern;

        base++;
    }

    std::cout << count << std::endl;
```

Running this returns 0, while it definitely should return >0

Comment: You never even look at `i`, which is the number you are supposedly testing. You instead look at `base`, which is initialized to zero and never changed afterwards.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I thought the same, but `base` is incremented at the bottom of the loop. It really should be next to `i++`.

Comment: Given that it's only 256 possible values, you can simply precompute which one of them contain the requisite bit pattern, create an array with 256 values, indicating whether each value has the bit pattern, then at this point the whole problem becomes a nothing-burger.

Comment: In this case are you looking for any sequence of 3 1's in a row? Or specifically `0b11100000`?

Comment: @JohnFilleau any three 1s or 0s

Comment: Please don't add answer in the question body. This site has a clear separation between questions and answers. If you fell you have something to add you can post your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, 5 low-order bits in `temp` are always 0, while only 4 low-order bits of `pattern` are.

But actually, you should separate mask and pattern, like

```
unsigned char mask = 0b0000'0111; // (1 << pattern length) - 1
unsigned char pattern1 = 0b0000'0111;
unsigned char pattern2 = 0b0000'0000;

temp >>= j;
if ((mask & temp) == pattern1 || (mask & temp) == pattern2)
```

This way, you can check for any subsequences.

Also the loop should be to 5 *inclusive*: the pattern can appear at bits (0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3), ..., (5, 6, 7).